# Attempting to launch logman.exe on a Windows Server 2008 R2 -- the command prompt opens and then immediately quits

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitor

Attempting to open logman.exe on a Windows 2008 server is somehow harder than it looks.

It launches, and then immediately quits without any warning or pop-up. I attempted to "Run as Administrator" but it does the same without any prompt. Is there any way to figure out why it is doing this? Perhaps it is something in my permissions/policy -- how would I go about fixing it or finding out what it is? I've attempted to launch it on multiple machines but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot. You have to open the command prompt, and then run 'logman.exe'. Leaving this up in case anyone else gets brain farts.